# how to show current location when moving onthe map on polyline same as navigation turn by turn in android

Tags: html

I create a map and get route from google map and show polyline on the map.and then get current location and show on the map But can not show marker(current location) on along polyline when moveing. hoe to set camera position behind the marker turn by turn same as this picture?

[image]

Comment: show what you have tried.. the code

Comment: Please edit your question, it is full of fault... It's no longer reading it's decoding ...